# Using stmaryrd with extpfeil

Tags: incompatibility, stmaryrd

Importing `extpfeil` seems to undefine some of the macros in `stmaryrd`. In particular LaTeX complains

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \Yleft
```

unless I delete `extpfeil`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{extpfeil}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}
$\Yleft$
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It would be ***much*** better if `extpfeil` did `\@ifpackageloaded{stmaryrd}{}{\RequirePackage[only,shortleftarrow,shortrightarrow]{stmaryrd}}` and warn in the documentation that it should be loaded after `stmaryrd`, if one wants the full force of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately `extpfeil` does

```
 \RequirePackage[only,shortleftarrow,shortrightarrow]{stmaryrd}
```

so `stmaryrd` is loaded in limited form, that means that if you load `stmaryrd` first you get an option clash error and if you load it later, only those arrows are defined.

Simplest thing (other than getting the above changed to not do that if `stmaryrd` package is already loaded) is to load `stmaryrd` first but then fake the package options so that no option clash error is issued:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\expandafter\def\csname opt@stmaryrd.sty\endcsname
{only,shortleftarrow,shortrightarrow}
\usepackage{extpfeil}


\begin{document}
$\Yleft$
\end{document}
```

This is surely bad style to poke into core latex definitions but anyway it loads `stmaryrd` with no options but falsely records that the options were 
`only,shortleftarrow,shortrightarrow` so when `extpfeil` tries to load it with these options latex just silently ignores the package load as it is recorded as having already been loaded with compatible options.